Multiple action through ansible default playbook
I have multiple tasks like Copy/Stop/Start so I created three yaml file based on the action. When I am passing single action then it is working fine but when I am passing two actions then playbook skipping the task.
Directory Structure.
Roles
.... App-deployment
 .... defaults
      .... main.yaml
 .... taks
      .... main.yaml
      .... copy.yaml
      .... star.yaml
      .... stop.yaml

In the main.yaml
- name: Copy jar
  include_tasks: copy.yaml
  when: action == 'copy'


- name: Stop sdf java jar running
  include_tasks: stop.yaml
  when: action == 'stop'

In the defaults > main.yaml
action: star

Then it is working but when I pass two action it is not working.
In the defaults > main.yaml
action: stop/start
action: stop, start 
action: "stop", "start"


Do not reinvent the wheel, use tags: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tags.html

I am not using ansible-playbook command, I am using harness tool to call the anisble playbook.
